# How can I simplify this code with for loop?

Tags: javascript, p5.js, rectangles

How can I change this code with for loop, so that I can create more bigger rectangles with same functions?
When I use for loop, when I point to the smaller rectangle, the bigger rectangle will also change color. I can't make it exclusive to the rectangle I am pointing at. Thankss.

```
let rectX = 200;
let rectY = 200;

let rect1Width = 80;
let rect1Height = 80;

let rect2Width = 40;
let rect2Height = 40;

let isMouseOverRect1 = false;
let isMouseOverRect2 = false;
let rect1 = false;
let rect2 = false;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  rectMode(CENTER);
}

function draw() {
  background(200);

  if (
    mouseX > rectX - rect1Width / 2 &&
    mouseX < rectX + rect1Width / 2 &&
    mouseY > rectY - rect1Height / 2 &&
    mouseY < rectY + rect1Height / 2
  ) {
    isMouseOverRect1 = true;
    rect1 = true;
  } else {
    isMouseOverRect1 = false;
    rect1 = false;
  }

  if (
    mouseX > rectX - rect2Width / 2 &&
    mouseX < rectX + rect2Width / 2 &&
    mouseY > rectY - rect2Height / 2 &&
    mouseY < rectY + rect2Height / 2
  ) {
    isMouseOverRect2 = true;
    rect2 = true;
  } else {
    isMouseOverRect2 = false;
    rect2 = false;
  }

  if (isMouseOverRect1 && !rect2) {
    fill(0);
  } else {
    fill(255);
  }
  rect(rectX, rectY, rect1Width, rect1Height);

  if (isMouseOverRect2 && rect1) {
    fill(0);
  } else {
    fill(255);
  }
  rect(rectX, rectY, rect2Width, rect2Height);
}
```

Drawing with for loop with same function.

Comment: Change all the global variables that specify the configuration of the rectangle to function parameters. With so many, it would probably be easier to pass them in a parameters object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can encapsulate reusable functionalities, for example:

- you can store rectangle properties (x, y, w, h) to redraw when needed using a single call
- you can write a reusable function to check if a point is inside a rectangle (instead of copy/pasting modifying the condition)

There are multiple ways to implement this depending on your level of comfort.
For example you could do something this:

- store the rectangle properties in an array(`[x,y,w,h]`) (or Object(`{x:200, y: 200, w:80, y:80}`)
- a reusable function that test if a point is inside a rectangle (data from above)

```js
let rect1 = {x:160, y:160, w:80, h:80}
let rect2 = {x:180, y:180, w:40, h:40};

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(200);
  
  let isOver1 = isOverRectangle(mouseX, mouseY, rect1);
  let isOver2 = isOverRectangle(mouseX, mouseY, rect2);
  
  fill(isOver1 && !isOver2 ? 0 : 255);
  drawRectangle(rect1);
  fill(isOver2 ? 0 : 255);
  drawRectangle(rect2);
}

function isOverRectangle(mx, my, rectangle){
  return (mx >= rectangle.x && mx <= (rectangle.x + rectangle.w)) && 
         (my >= rectangle.y && my <= (rectangle.y + rectangle.h));
}

function drawRectangle(r){
  rect(r.x, r.y, r.w, r.h);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.7.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively you could [define a class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

```js
class Rect{
  
  constructor(x, y, w, h){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
  }
  
  draw(){
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
  }
  
  isOver(mx, my){
    return (mx >= this.x && mx <= (this.x + this.w)) && 
           (my >= this.y && my <= (this.y + this.h));
  }
  
}

let rect1 = new Rect(160, 160, 80, 80);
let rect2 = new Rect(180, 180, 40, 40);

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(200);
  
  let isOver1 = rect1.isOver(mouseX, mouseY);
  let isOver2 = rect2.isOver(mouseX, mouseY);
  
  fill(isOver1 && !isOver2 ? 0 : 255);
  rect1.draw();
  fill(isOver2 ? 0 : 255);
  rect2.draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.7.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

For two rectangles you might not need a for loop, however if you do choose to encapsulation will make this a bit easier now. It will be a fun challenge for yourself, especially working out the logic to check which boxes to ignore and take into account to change the fill color. Have fun!

Comment: Try not to pollute the global scope by using `isOver1` etc.